# Running NodeJS script with privileged permissions - no console output

Tags: node.js, sudo

I'm using `node@18.15.0` and `pnpm@8.6.5` and `sudo-prompt@9.2.1`. I have the following command I want to execute `node ./test.cjs`, but with privileged permissions.

When I execute it without permissions, it works and I see logs.
This is the file content of `test.cjs` script:

```js
const sudoPrompt = require('sudo-prompt');

sudoPrompt.exec('node ./scripts/spawn-process.cjs', (error) => {
   if (error) {
      throw error;
   }
});
```

then, the `scripts/spawn-process.cjs` file content:

```js
const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

const spawner = spawn('webpack', ['--config', './webpack/webpack.config.dev.ts'], {
    windowsHide: true,
    shell: true,
    stdio: 'pipe',
});

process.stdin.pipe(spawner.stdin);

spawner.stdout?.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});

spawner.stderr?.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});

spawner.on('close', (exitCode) => {
    process.exit(exitCode);
});
```

Everything is working, the command is spawned successfully and running as required, **but I don't see any output in the terminal from the `console.log`**. When I run the `webpack` command as npm script: `"test": "webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.config.dev.ts"`, and then running `sudo pnpm test` (for example in macOS), I do see output in the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937488/3930247?

Comment: @technophyle
No, this is exactly what I've done

Comment: the callback in `sudoPrompt.exec` also takes a `stdout` and `stderr` . So probably those are captured during execution and passed to the callback once the execution is finished ...

Comment: @derpirscher Maybe, but it does not help here. I need to log it in real time to the console and this is why I run `spawn`. The command won't be executed within few seconds. It can take infinity time